# How is this "pathmax modification," $f(n^\prime) = \max(g(n^\prime) + h(n^\prime), f(n))$, useful?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, heuristics, a-star-search

I am studying the concept of **heuristics** in search algorithms, and the [$A^*$ search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm) in particular. I am told the following:

> Greedy search minimises estimated path-cost to goal.
>
> - But it's neither optimal nor even always complete.
>
> Uniform-cost search minimises path-cost from the start.
>
> - Complete and optimal, but expensive.
>
> Can we get the best of both worlds?
>
> - Yes - use *estimate of total path-cost* as our heuristic.
>
> $f(n) = g(n) + h(n)$
>
> - $g(n) =$ ***actual** cost from start to $n$*
> - $h(n) =$ ***estimated** cost from $n$ to goal*
> - $f(n) =$ *estimated total cost from start to goal **via n***
>
> $A^*$ search is *complete* and *optimal* under two conditions:
>
> - The heuristic must be *admissible*.
> - The costs along a given path must be *monotonic*.
>
> A heuristic $h$ is admissible iff $h(n) \le h^*(n)$ for all $n$.
>
> - $h^*(n)$ is the *actual* path-cost from $n$ to the goal.
>
> i.e., $h$ must never over-estimate the cost.
>
> - e.g., $h_{SLD}$ never over-estimates
>
> A heuristic $h$ is monotonic iff $h(n) \le c(n, a, n^\prime) + h(n^\prime)$, for all $n$, $a$, $n^\prime$.
>
> - $n^\prime$ is a successor to $n$ by action $a$.
>   – This is basically the triangle inequality.
> - $n$ to the goal "directly" should be no more than $n$ to the goal via any successor $n^\prime$.
>
> Pathmax modification: $f(n^\prime) = \max(g(n^\prime) + h(n^\prime), f(n))$.
>
> Note that optimal here means "finds the best goal."
>
> We are not arguing that $h$ itself is optimal in any sense.

How is this "pathmax modification," $f(n^\prime) = \max(g(n^\prime) + h(n^\prime), f(n))$, useful? I can understand what it's doing by looking at the individual components, but I don't really understand the point of it. I get the impression that I'm missing/misunderstanding/overlooking something here.

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing.  Please [edit] your post accordingly.

Comment: What resources have you checked?  Have you looked for a textbook that explains pathmax in more detail?  Slides or bullet points are not an ideal learning resource; they are not a substitute for a textbook, lecture notes, or other primary resource.

Comment: @D.W. This is just what was mentioned on some slides. I was hoping that someone more knowledgeable would clarify.

Comment: The heuristic will be monotone, and furthermore the higher value (as long as it's admissible) the better. Meaning that if the heuristic value ($f+g$) actually drops from one node to the next, we can just keep the higher value.

Comment: @PålGD Hmm, yes, I think your comment touches on something that I suspect I'm not fully understanding. I've been doing some thinking and have some related, fundamental questions to ask about heuristics (in another question).

Comment: Slides are often not a good resource for understanding technical material in depth.  I suggest spending some time in the library to consult some textbooks to see what you can find, and searching on the Internet for lecture notes.  Slides are not a substitute for a textbook or detailed lecture notes.  We encourage you to do a significant amount of research before asking here, and show us what research you've done and what you've found in the question.  See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/781723.