# If the heuristic $h(n)$ is the estimated cost from node $n$ to the goal, then why would we want a heuristic that has a greater cost?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, heuristics

I am currently studying the concept of **heuristics** in search algorithms. I recently asked [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/154952/66333) about the so-called "pathmax modification," $f(n^\prime) = \max(g(n^\prime) + h(n^\prime), f(n))$, and how it is useful. The [user Pål GD](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/4249/p%C3%A5l-gd) commented with the following:

> The heuristic will be monotone, and furthermore the higher value (as long as it's admissible) the better. Meaning that if the heuristic value $(f + g)$ actually drops from one node to the next, we can just keep the higher value.

Furthermore, I am told the following:

> We say that $h_2$ dominates $h_1$ iff they are both admissible, and $h_2(n) \ge h_1(n)$, for all nodes $n$.
>
> - i.e., $h^*(n) \ge h_2(n) \ge h_1(n)$
>
> If $h_2$ dominates $h_1$, then $A^*$ with $h_2$ will usually visit fewer nodes than $A^*$ with $h_1$.
>
> The "proof" is obvious:
>
> - $A^*$ visits all nodes $n$ with $f(n) < f^*$.
> - i.e., it visits all nodes with $h(n) < f^* - g(n)$.
> - $f^*$ and $g(n)$ are fixed.
>   So if $h(n)$ is bigger, $n$ is less likely to be below-the-line.

$g(n) =$ ***actual** cost from start to $n$*.
$h(n) =$ ***estimated** cost from $n$ to goal*.
$f(n) =$ *estimated total cost from start to goal **via n***.
$f^*$ is the actual cost of the optimal solution.

After studying this, and especially the proof, and then reading Pål GD's comment, it is clear to me that I am not understanding the concept of heuristics.

Clearly, the concept of a *dominant* heuristic says that the greater heuristic is "superior." And then, in the proof, it says that, since $f^*$ and $g(n)$ are fixed, for $h(n) < f^* - g(n)$, if $h(n)$ is bigger, then $n$ is less likely to be "below-the-line." But none of this makes sense to me. If the heuristic $h(n)$ is the estimated cost from node $n$ to the goal, then **why would we want a heuristic that has a *greater* cost**? For search problems, aren't we looking for the *lowest* cost path to the goal? And **why would the heuristic that has the *greater* cost be more likely to visit fewer nodes**? Doesn't the fact that it has a *greater* cost mean that it has taken a more unfavourable path to the goal, thereby leading to greater cost? It seems to me that this misunderstanding is at the core of why I wasn't understanding the usefulness of the "pathmax modification."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that the heuristic is always *under-estimating* the cost from a node to the target, which means that a higher cost (closer to the true value) is always a more accurate cost.

For example, suppose that your landscape is a grid (like Manhattan) with some potential road-blocks.  Then you can let the heuristic for node $n$ to the target $t$ be the $\ell_2$ distance, i.e. $$h_2(n) = \sqrt{ (n_x - t_x)^2 + (n_y - t_y)^2},$$
but a better heuristic would be the $\ell_1$ distance (the Manhattan distance), i.e. $h_1(n) = (n_x - t_x) + (n_y - t_y)$.

Notice that $h_1$ is always at least as high as $h_2$, both are under-estimating, which means that $h_1$ is a more accurate cost.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isn't the $L_1$ distance the Manhattan distance? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry

Comment: Indeed it is. I stand corrected.

Comment: Ok, so I understand what you're saying here: a heuristic is always *under*-estimating the cost, and so a greater heuristic more accurately estimates the cost. But there's still one point I'm not clear on: why would the heuristic that has the greater cost be more likely to visit fewer nodes? If a heuristic is always underestimating the cost, and so a greater heuristic more accurately estimates the cost, then how does it make sense that the more accurate heuristic, which has a greater cost, be more likely to visit *fewer* nodes? Still, it seems that greater cost means more nodes visited, no?

Comment: Let $h(n)$ be the true cost of getting from $n$ to the goal $t$. In other words, let $h$ be the heuristic that is as high as possible. Which nodes will be expanded?

Comment: Hmm, that's a good question. I want to say something like "the shortest / lowest cost path of nodes to the goal," but, given that we just established that our goal is not to *minimise* the value of the heuristic, but to have it *as close to the actual cost as possible*, I guess I'd now say something like "those nodes that are as close as possible (that is, have minimal deviation from) the optimal path." So, basically, if the true cost is $h^*(n) = 500$, then the path of nodes that results in the smallest deviation from $h^*(n) = 500$ is what will be expanded. [...]

Comment: [...] This would align with the idea that we want to have it as close as possible to the actual cost. But I guess it just sounds counter-intuitive, since my first instinct is to think of it as an optimisation-type problem, where we would be trying to minimise the value in an absolute sense, rather than minimise the deviation of the value from the "true value/cost," which is what we seem to be wanting to do with heuristics.

Comment: It seems like you're thinking about minimizing the cost of the nodes that actually are on the path to the goal.  However, there are very few of those.  And very many of the nodes that aren't.  We are trying to maximizing the value on the useless nodes.

Comment: I think that's what I was trying to say: we're basically trying to find the best/optimal path out of the nodes that are available. Since there usually isn't a "perfect" path of nodes, like a straight path of nodes directly from start to goal, we have to find the "optimal" path using the "non-perfect" nodes that exist.